# convert camera 2 target 3d absolute cordinates to relative cordinates for pose estimation

Tags: python, opencv, augmented-reality, pose-estimation, opencv-solvepnp

I was trying to caluculate pose estimation of the object
To get rotation matrix from solve pnp ,inputs i have image points ,world points (cam2target),cam_*mat,dist_*coeff

The problem is solve pnp input obj points  accecpt 3d relative pointi have 3d absolute point  ,so how to convert my absolute cordinates to get relative cordinate to find the rotation matrix

i tried to find the relative cordinates from absolute coordinates using eculidean distance (not worked)

i tried inverting the rvec and tvec output from the solvepnp(not worked)